# Checked attribute in checkbox IE

Tags: jquery

While appending input element with checked attribut as below code

```
$("#addcheckbox").append("<input type='checkbox' value=\"Hi\" checked='checked'>"); // addcheckbox is div
```

In IE the rendered element looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" CHECKED="" value="Hi"/>
```

This occurs after using jquery 1.7.2 before that it was like below

```
<input type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" value="Hi"/>
```

because of this, i am facing lot if issues with jquery templating.

any help

Thanks

Comment: Try using the `.attr()` and set the checked attribute explicitly, you don't really need the escape sequences there

Comment: Could be related to this jquery bug report: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you were not closing the input properly.. Close the tag and try again..

```
$("#addcheckbox").append("<input type='checkbox' value='Hi' checked='checked' />");
```

OR

```
$('<input/>', {  
    type: 'checkbox',  
    value: 'Hi',  
    checked: 'checked'  
}).appendTo('#addCheckBox') ;
```

Also What is #addCheckBox Here.. Is it a Div??